# Event not fired when Full Page Cache is enabled in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache

I am trying to run a piece of code on every page load. I have the following

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="csp" instance="MyVendor\MyModule\Observers\MyObserver" shared="false" disabled="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

This works besides from when Full Page Cache is enabled. When it is enabled my observer does not run.

Is there a better event I should watch to enable me to run code on every page load regardless of if Full Page Cache is turned on or off?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a better event for it but you could instead use a plugin.

The FPC plugs into [\Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface::dispatch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface.php) you could define a plugin in order to execute your method before the FPC kicks in.

The FPC plugin is defined [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/68c48d55231de6849195e090e2b3ce750db61825/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/frontend/di.xml#L10).